# In Struts, how do I give a value contained in key to a href

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a key attribute that holds a value like, "www.google.com". In textbox, the value is being displayed. But how do I make it display as a link in href tag?

Comment: You render it into an HREF tag or use it as value in an `<s:url>` tag.

Comment: I am rendering it as a HREF tag

Comment: Then what's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Please find below using this you can give value:

```
<s:url value="x" id="x"> <s:param name="y" value="y" /> </s:url>
```